# datepicker not working inside ng-view with bootstrap-datepicker

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I am trying to implement the datepicker plugin developped by [eternicode](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker) and I am experiencing some hurdles with ng-view.

I found similar cases but none helped me solving this (e.g. controller in the routeProvider) :

When my datepicker is inside index.html it works fine, but when I use a template view, the calendar doesn't popup.

Here's a plunkr to illustrate this case : [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/yzoagt9Mw7WAYOBNRWgS?p=preview)

```
<div ng-view></div>

  <div class="container">
      <div class="col-lg-2">
          <div class="input-group date">
              <input type="text" class="form-control"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time when the js is running at the bottom of your index.html file, the view hasn't been loaded yet.

I moved the plugin code initialization code to the controller to demonstrate that it will work if the code is executed after the view has been loaded. You may want to rethink how you are setting up your app.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/PDX500tp5QgcjIMIbig1?p=preview

UPDATED: using a directive instead: http://plnkr.co/edit/LVKHkmNrTS2Ki7uP8Hgj?p=preview

Comment: Strangely this works nicely in a view but not when I embed it inside an element defined by directive. And if I wrap the template with `<div ng-controller=MainCtrl>   </div>` it works but all other functions are turned off.. How do you define a directive in your plnkr? It doesn't work when I do a `app.directive('element')`...

Comment: can you provide an updated..plunker so I can see exactly what you mean. Then I will update the answer.

Comment: I updated the answer and linked to another plunker that demonstrates using a directive.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I finally managed to make it work in my application structure thanks to your answer and some workarounds. Somehow it didn't work properly : I have 2 datepickers inside a directive which is inside another directive. I've been using ng-if to make the datepicker elments appear but then the popup didn't work. I tried with ng-show and then it worked!

Comment: Thanks a lot... Very good example and superb explanation, continue the good work.